Energy scale for random matrix theory
Consider a random matrix $M$ of size $d$ ($d$ being a very large integer) sampled from the GUE, that is, we take $M=G+G^*$ where the coefficients of $G$ are iid complex normal variables with zero mean and variance $1$.
If we would like $M$ to model a random Hamiltonian for a quantum system, what scale (in terms of $d$) should we choose? If I am correct, if we want constant average spacing between the eigenvalues, we should take $M$; but if we want the range of the spectrum, we should take $\frac{M}{\sqrt{d}}$. Which one is the physically relevant scale?
For example, it is often said that Wigner used random matrix theory to reason about energy levels of large nuclei. Did he use GUE? Which normalization did he choose?

Some people have voted to close the question. I would find it helpful if some explanation was given.
